# Checkbox Inside While in PHP

Tags: php

In the Below Code,CheckBox didn't come on the first rows of the Table.Can any one Help me..

rgds,
Sirojan

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"

<?php
$dbc=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","elvis_store") or die("Error Connecting to Mysql Database");

$query="SELECT * FROM email_list";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query)or die("Query Syntaxt is Incorrect");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['id'].'" name="todelete[]"/>';
    echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']." ".$row['email'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>

<input type="submit" name"submit" value="Remove"/>
</body>
```

Comment: I think your code is incomplete , please post correct code and format it accordingly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `form` tag is not closed on the first line

```
<form method="post" action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"
```

it should be

```
<form method="post" action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```